# How to find Memory SIZE of records returned in a SQL Query in Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, size, heap-memory

I am hitting a query which returns 10,000 Records.

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id < 11000;
```

The data returned consists of 85 Columns (varchar, date, no.). 
(Also i have another similar query gets data consist of just 10 columns(varchar).)

Is there any way in Oracle to find the data size of this resultset? Like the data loaded will be of 100 MB or 200 MB

**Requirement**: Actually i need to load all records in memory; for these records for some processing in Java. So i need to check size of data using some preconditions in Oracle or Any other appropriate way you can suggest to check same? (I have production access. So i will implement logic after checking data size).

This precheck is just to avoid Out of memory exceptions in java.

IF i copy whole data and save it in file it shows only 604 KB for 10,000 records having 8 columns. Does the same will there in memory?

Comment: What do you mean by data size? Do you mean the number of columns?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz I think it's the size in bytes (or any similar unit) which is comparable to the RAM size somehow.

Comment: use this: select count(*) from employee where id < 11000;

Comment: What size do you want? The size of a record as stored on disk in the database? The size of a record as transmitted to the client? The size of a record as stored in Java memory? Stored how? In a POJO? In a `Map`? Please edit question and clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: *"i need to load all records in memory; for these records for some processing in Java"* Hmmm... Are you going to write those records back to the database after this processing?

Comment: @APC: O i think my question is not clear... No i just want to see how much MB that data is when we hit SQL Query as i have to avoid memory issues in java program; so configure things accordingly. Edited my Question

Comment: @Andreas: O Sorry, i have edited my question. Here i mean to if i load 10,000 records in memory using java then how much size it will take like 100 MB or what and how it can be calculated using oracle query or other ways. Reedited question

Comment: @ZeinabGhaffarnasab: Thanks. SOrry for confusion. Edited my queston. It is Memory size which i want to calculate when objects load in memory

Comment: @deHaar: Thanks for understanding, i have done some editing may be now things are clear

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz: Sorry for bothering, i have edited my question, here i meant how to calculate how much data is loaded in memory (in oracle or other way)

Comment: Well, varchar columns can contains values varying length (hence the name) so the strings that will be created in Java will have different memory requirements as well. That being said it might be hard to calculate the exact amount of memory needed because there might be multiple references (each of those already uses up some memory even if refering to the same object) in multiple locations (like the result set, in your application, some driver internal location etc.). ...

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks, but like if i copied whole data in file it says 604KB text file. But when it comes to Java Platform then in memory for same data will it be like jump to 10 MB or will it like 1024 KB? Could you please give some rough idea in the use case

Comment: But you should be able to _estimate_ the memory that could be needed and in most cases that's probably enough (if you're operating on hard restrictions that might not be the case but those restrictions rarely exist in business applications): get the size of each data type your results would contain (like `Integer`, `Date` etc.) and the maximum length of your strings. Add all those up and multiply with 10k and you should get a reasonable estimate already.

Comment: @Thomas
So as per your suggestion if i have 8 string variables(store everything into string) and each string variable say consume - 40 byte for empty (or 20 char) and so for 100 character 200Bytes almost and by this 1600 Byte for 8 String variables. So for 10,000 it will take 16 000 000 byte = 16 megabytes...Cool...

Comment: Yes that's about it. Note that Java objects have a lot of internal fields and references so they require a lot more memory than just the basic primitive types (e.g. an `Integer` would require at least 16 bytes: 12 for the object header and 4 for the int value). Additionally writing data into a text file would change the size because that depends on the encoding (Latin-1 would use 1 byte per char while Java strings already use 2 bytes per char) and if you transform small integers to text that will require less memory as well.

Comment: "If i copy whole data and save it in file it shows only 604 KB for 10,000 records having 8 columns." - let's assume you're using Latin-1 here, no column delimiters and no compression. That would mean that you'd have (604 * 1024 - 10000 / 10000) = 60.8 bytes per row on average (that - 10000 is because you'd need row delimiters at least). That would mean that each column would need 7.6 bytes on average. Let's round that up to 8 and thus your 80000 columns would need 1280000 bytes (1.2 MB) for the character data alone (8 * 80000 * 2).

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for detailed insight. You can share it in answer. Not sure if it has oracle perspective too to calculate data size according to query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you can use Java's instrumentation capabilities to determine the memory consumption at runtime. For some information on that have a look here:

- [How to determine the size of an object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-size-of-object

However, it is not always that easy to determine the actual memory consumption for various reasons, some of them being:

- Frameworks, libraries and even the JVM might create copies of your data or cache and reuse it
- Queries might return differently sized results, especially when variable length column types like VARCHAR are used. You'd have to read that data to determine the actual size of the corresponding objects
- Some objects might be referenced by multiple others so their size might be included incorrectly (e.g. if some enum constant is used that might be counted into the object size but it wouldn't actually add to the increase because it's most likely already been loaded anyway).

Additionally in most business applications you don't need to bother with determining the exact memory consumption a piece of code results in. Again there are various reasons, e.g.:

- Memory is cheap so if you run into problems it's often easier to (at least temporarily) increase available memory than (micro-) optimizing a piece of code.
- System usage and load often isn't as predictable due to changing situations (e.g. number of active users, changes in data etc.)
- The JVM often is able to efficiently use garbage collection to reclaim memory for other things.

This doesn't mean that you shouldn't think about memory usage though, e.g. do you really need all those 10k rows in memory at once? How long do you need that data and what are you doing with it?

That being said it's often helpful to roughly estimate memory consumption and in the case of a query that could return a lot of strings you should estimate the worst case, i.e. assume maximum length strings.

To do that you'll need some knowledge about what your rows will contain, e.g. whether integer numbers `Integer`, `Long` or `BigInteger` instances or how many columns there could be. Additionally you'll need to know at least the memory requirements for the data types, i.e. we don't take any caching, duplication, overhead for `ResultSet` and the like into account.

The sizes for Java objects depend on various things, e.g. which JVM you're using, whether it is a 32- or 64-bit JVM etc. Various sources state that an object's memory consumption can be calculated from the Object header (which often is stated to be 12 bytes in size) and the size of the object's fields.

Using that we'll assume `Integer` to have a size of 16 bytes (12b header and 4b `int`), `Date` would be 24 bytes (12b header, 8b `fastTime` and 4b `cdate` reference), String would be 12b header, 4b char[] reference, 8b other fields, 12h char[] header and 2*length bytes for the characters themselves (or 36 + 2 * length in total).

Thus let's say your 85 columns are split into 20 integers, 10 dates and 55 strings of 256 bytes max length. One row would that need *at least* 20 * 16 + 10 * 24 + 55 * 548 = 30700 bytes. 10k rows would thus need 307000000 bytes or roughly 300 MB (when all strings are at maximum length).

> If I copy whole data and save it in file it shows only 604 KB for 10,000 records having 8 columns.

Let's break that down a little as well:

- 604 KB would be 618496 bytes (1024 being one KB)
- Devide that by 10k and you get 61.8 bytes per row on average
- Devide that by 8 and you get 7.7 bytes per column (if we don't take any row or column delimiters into account)
- Let's round it up to 8 bytes per column and let's assume your text file is Latin-1 encoded (so 1 byte per char), thus each text column has 8 chars on average which is pretty short

In an easier calculation, if we use the same asumptions as above, 604KB would mean your data would consist of roughly 604k characters, which in Java would need 1208k bytes (or about 1.2 MB) just for the character data alone. Add to that the overhead for 80k strings, i.e. 36 bytes * 80k which is about 2.8 MB more so that data would need about 4 MB in memory.